# Threading a list of functions over a list of arguments

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to produce `{Foo[a,b, c], Goo[a, b, c], Hoo[a, b, c]}`. However my attempt below

```
Thread[Apply[{Foo, Goo, Hoo}, HoldComplete@Sequence[a, b, c]]]
```

produces `{Foo, Goo, Hoo}[a, b, c]`.

Could you fix it?

Comment: `Construct[#, Sequence[a,b,c]] & /@ {Foo, Goo, Hoo}` ... or if you want to keep the hold and release: `ReleaseHold[Construct[#, HoldComplete@Sequence[x, y, z]] & /@ {Foo, Goo, Hoo}]`

Comment: Let me know if my solution would work for you, or how I might improve it :D

Comment: @flinty: Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html):

```
Through[{Foo, Goo, Hoo} @@ {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {Foo[a, b, c], Goo[a, b, c], Hoo[a, b, c]}
> ```

Alternatively, use it as:

```
Through @ {Foo, Goo, Hoo}[a, b, c]
```

> ```
> {Foo[a, b, c], Goo[a, b, c], Hoo[a, b, c]}
> ```

Or make it into a function:

```
boohoo = Through[# @@ #2] &;

{Foo, Goo, Hoo} ~ boohoo ~ {a, b, c}
```

> ```
>  {Foo[a, b, c], Goo[a, b, c], Hoo[a, b, c]}
> ```

Answer (score 8):

```
func={Foo,Goo,Hoo};
arg={a,b,c};

#@@arg&/@func
```

> ```
> {Foo[a,b,c],Goo[a,b,c],Hoo[a,b,c]}
> ```

Let me know if you need an explanation. I figure a list of both functions and arguments would be the simplest method. Then I just made sure the `Map` over the functions would cause them to `Apply` to the arguments.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer glad to hear it! Looks like kglr beat me again though haha D;

Answer (score 3):

Using `ComapApply` (new in 14.0)

```
ComapApply[{Foo, Goo, Hoo}] @ {a, b, c}
```

{Foo[a, b, c], Goo[a, b, c], Hoo[a, b, c]}

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022 we have at our disposal the resource function called [**`ThroughOperator`**](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ThroughOperator/) that can do that. This is a development thanks to @Sjoerd Smit.

With

```
functions = {Foo, Goo, Hoo};
arguments = {a, b, c};
```

we do

```
ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][functions] @@ arguments
```

and we get:

> `{Foo[a, b, c], Goo[a, b, c], Hoo[a, b, c]}`

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `Thread`:

```
f = Activate[#1 @@@ #2 & @@@ Thread[{#1, Inactive[#2]}]] &;

f @@ {{Foo, Goo, Hoo}, {a, b, c}}

(*{Foo[a, b, c], Goo[a, b, c], Hoo[a, b, c]}*)
```